# CS50 Vigenere - Strange pattern

Tags: c, encryption, vigenere, cs50

I am having a bit of an issue with Vigenere, and would like some help.

```
/*
This program is a Vigenere Cipher.
I am Daniel of Asguard.
*/

#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
string cipher; //this is a placeholder for the ciphered message.
char * key = argv[1];
int i = 0;


if (argc != 2) //this is meant to trigger if you don't enter the right call. So 
{
    printf("Please enter the cipher key when you call the program, such as './CaesarCipher 7'.\n"); //
    return 1;
}

if (!isalpha(key[i])) //this is meant to trigger if you don't enter the right call. So 
{
    printf("Please only enter a word, no numerical numbers please."); //
    return 1;
}

do
{
    //printf("Please enter the message you would like to have converted, please. \n");
    cipher =  GetString(); 
}
while (cipher == NULL);

for (int i = 0, k = 0, n = strlen(cipher); i < n; i++, k++) //this is so the code knows to change only the characters in the sting cipher.
    {
        if (k >= strlen(key))
        {
            k = 0;
        }
            {
            if (isupper(cipher[i]))
                {
                    //cipher[i] = 'A' + (((cipher[i] - 'A') + (key[k]) - 'A')  % 26);
                    cipher[i] = ((key[k] - 65) + (cipher[i] - 65)) % 26;
                    printf("%s\n", cipher);
                }
            else (islower(cipher[i]));
                {
                    //cipher[i] = 'a' + (((cipher[i] - 'a') + (key[i]) - 'a') % 26);
                    cipher[i] = ((key[k] - 97) + (cipher[i] - 97)) % 26;
                    printf("%s\n", cipher);
                }
        }
    }
printf("%s\n", cipher);
return 0;
}
```

When I do this my results get weird characters: ⎽c▒⎺e┼├⎼▒┤└e⎼@☃de5▮:·/┬⎺⎼┐⎽⎻▒ce/⎻⎽e├2 $ └▒┐e ┴☃±e┼e⎼e for all the letters in my terminal after completing.

My results end up looking like this for BaZ:

- Anything of Note
- nything of Note
- ything of Note
- ything of Note
- thing of Note
- ing of Note
- ing of Note
- ng of Note
- of Note
- of Note
- f Note
- f Note
- Note
- ote
- ote
- ote
- ├e
- e

Answer (score 0):

The code below work as expected acc to example in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{ 
    const char  *cipher = "ATTACKATDAWN";
    const char  *key = "LEMON";
    char *newkey;
    char *p, *q;
    int i =0;
    int col, row;
    if (strlen (key) < strlen (cipher))
    {
printf ("key %s \n", key);
printf ("cipher \t%s \n", cipher);
newkey = malloc ( strlen (cipher) +1);
strcpy ( newkey, key);
p = (char *) (newkey + strlen (newkey)) ;
q = (char *) key; 
i =strlen (key);
while (i < strlen (cipher) )
{
        i++;
        if (*q == 0)
    q = (char *) key;
        *p = *q;
        p++;
        q++;
}
    *p = 0;
    printf ("newk \t%s \n", newkey);
    }
    p = (char *) newkey;
    q= (char *) cipher;
    int a[1] ;
    a[1] =0;
    for (i =0  ; i < strlen(newkey); i++)
    {
row = *p -65;
col = *q -65;
if (col+row > 26)
        a [0] = 65 + col+row -26;
else
        a [0] = 65 +col+row;
printf ("%s",(char *)  &a[0]);
p++;
q++;
    }
    printf ("\n");
    free( newkey);
/*L X F O P V E F R N H R*/
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the line:

```
cipher[i] = ((key[k] - 65) + (cipher[i] - 65)) % 26;
```

you've forgotten to add back 65 (the ASCII code of `A`) to the result.  Thus, `cipher[i]` will be a character from 0 to 25, all of which are non-printable control codes (and the null / 0 character, in particular, is treated by C string functions as an end-of-string marker).

The line:

```
cipher[i] = ((key[k] - 97) + (cipher[i] - 97)) % 26;
```

has the same error.

Also, on both lines, you're assuming that the key character has the same case as the message character you're encrypting.  If that's not the case, your encryption results will be incorrect.  To fix this, I would suggest converting the whole key into all upper (or lower) case *before* the main encryption loop.

You could also go a step further, and convert the key to numbers between 0 and 25 before the loop.  However, you won't be able to use `strlen()` on the key after you do this, since `strlen()` looks for the position of the first null (= 0) character in the string.  Instead, you'd have to run `strlen()` before converting the key, and save its result in a variable for later use.  Actually, this would be a useful optimization in any case (and you should do it for the message, too).